# Difference between "errors/exceptions" and "throw/catch"?

Tags: exception, error-handling, rebol, rebol3

I'm a bit confused over error handling in Rebol.  It has THROW and CATCH constructions:

```
>> repeat x 10 [if x = 9 [throw "Nine!"]]
** Throw error: no catch for throw: make error! 2

>> catch [repeat x 10 [if x = 9 [throw "Nine!"]]]
== "Nine!"
```

But this throwing and catching is unrelated to the handler passed to the /EXCEPT refinement on TRY:

```
>> try/except [throw "Nine!"] [print "Exception handled!"]
** Throw error: no catch for throw: make error! 2
```

That's very specific to Rebol's error type:

```
>> try/except [print 1 / 0] [print "Error handled!"]
Error handled!
```

If you want you can trigger your own errors, but not using THROW as you would in other languages.  Throwing errors will just lead to a complaint about not being caught, as any other value type:

```
>> try/except [throw make error! "Error string"] [print "Error handled!"]
** Throw error: no catch for throw: make error! 2
```

You must DO them to get the evaluator to try and execute something of type error! to cause what it considers an *"exception"*:

```
>> try/except [do make error! "Error string"] [print "Error handled!"]
Error handled!
```

*(Note: You can [use pre-made errors apparently](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54466/interface-and-implementation-of-this-replacement-for-rebol-red-rejoin#comment96667_54765) such as `cause-error 'Script 'invalid-type function!` -- see `system/catalog/errors` for more.)*

Leaving off the /EXCEPT refinement will let you receive any errors as a value.  However, that seems to make it impossible to distinguish between whether the error was invoked or not:

```
>> probe try [do make error! "Some error"]
make error! [
    code: 800
    type: 'User
    id: 'message
    arg1: "some error"
    arg2: none
    arg3: none
    near: none
    where: none
]
** User error: "Some error"

>> probe try [make error! "Some error"]
make error! [
    code: 800
    type: 'User
    id: 'message
    arg1: "Some error"
    arg2: none
    arg3: none
    near: none
    where: none
]
** User error: "Some error"
```

It would seem that CATCH has a similar lack of distinction between returning a value and having a value thrown.  But there's a tool to get around that with "named throws":

```
>> code: [repeat x 10 [if x = 9 [throw/name "Nine!" 'number]]]

>> catch/name [do code] 'number
== "Nine!"

>> catch/name [do code] 'somethingelse
** Throw error: no catch for throw: make error! 2
```

So now for the questions:

- Is there a practical value to this separation?  How does one decide whether to use THROW and CATCH or a DO of an error and handle it with TRY/EXCEPT?
- Does this distinction have precedent in other languages, and would /EXCEPT be better named /ON-ERROR or something?
- Why does it say `"no catch for throw: make error! 2"` instead of something more informative?  What is the `make error! 2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "Is there a practical value to this separation? How does one decide whether to use THROW and CATCH or a DO of an error and handle it with TRY/EXCEPT?"

As has been pointed out in the other answers as well, THROW and CATCH form an unwinding construct (a non-local exit) that in and of itself is concerned with control flow and doesn't necessarily have anything to do with error handling. THROW and CATCH is first and foremost a straightforward method to influence control flow and is a rather fundamental building block for other custom control flow constructs.

As such, THROW and CATCH can of course also be used for building an "exception handling"-like error system as seen in many contemporary mainstream languages, because those "exception handling" systems are one instance of non-local control flow.

Rebol's `error!` on the other hand is the primary method to signal and propagate evaluation errors.

So generally, the decision is easy to make: if you want to cause an error, use `error!`. If you want to influence control flow to unwind controllably, use THROW / CATCH.

Two more remarks regarding terminology:

- Discussion around Rebol errors [has become more careful](http://issue.cc/r3/1491) to use "*cause* an error" as a phrase instead of "throw an error", to avoid confusion.
- In a similar vein, references that call THROW / CATCH "Rebol's exception handling" (as @HostileFork alludes to in one comment) need to be reworked.

> "Does this distinction have precedent in other languages"

Yes, the distinction between evaluation errors and non-local exits has precedent in other languages, especially the Lisp family. A few quick references:

- Common Lisps's [`catch`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_catch.htm) and [`throw`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_throw.htm) vs [condition signaling](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/09_ada.htm)
- Emacs Lisp's [`catch` and `throw`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Catch-and-Throw.html) vs [error signaling](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Errors.html)
- Dylan's [`block`](http://opendylan.org/books/drm/Statement_Macros#block) vs the [condition system](http://opendylan.org/books/drm/Conditions_Overview)

> "Why does it say "no catch for throw: make error! 2" instead of something more informative? What is the make error! 2?"

That's a bug. (Good catch!) I'd say that the core of the error message ("no catch for throw") is rather informative already, but the `make error! 2` is a bug (it should rather show the thrown value here.)

> "would /EXCEPT be better named /ON-ERROR or something?"

Renaming `/EXCEPT` is debatable. As such, I'd say this is a discussion not that suitable for SO Q&A and better left to other fora.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the regular throw is not for error handling, but for shortcuts or **goto**. It serves something as a break in loops etc. You could use it also to mimic a **continue**

See [is-there-an-equivalent-to-continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673867/is-there-an-equivalent-to-continue-python-in-rebol)

Comment: A definition of exception handling that sounds reasonable to me is: *"an exception is when a member fails to complete the task it is supposed to perform as indicated by its name."*  By that definition, I would say that there needs to be another category for THROW/CATCH; perhaps call it "Rebol's unwinding operations" vs. "Rebol's exception handling"...

Answer (score 2):

I am not very familiar with error handling in Rebol, but the point about exceptions and throwing and catching is that they are often thought of as "error handling" constructs, which is a rather narrow concept. Instead, it is better to think of try/catch as a flow control mechanism. But whereas exiting a loop just exits an immediate surrounding block, the benefit you get from throwing an exception is that it can straddle a number of frames in the stack. You can therefore isolate individual blocks of code more easily as a logical unit, which, if any part of it fails, can be treated as a failure of the logical unit, regardless of how far down in the stack the exception occurs.

Sorry, that did maybe not answer your question directly, but I thought I could address your second point: whether it should be called ON-ERROR. I would say no, because an exception does not necessarily imply an error; as a means of flow control it is just a more general instruction that a condition occurred that shouldn't allow further execution down a specific path.

Comment: I mentioned in another comment that I liked the definition *"an exception is when a member fails to complete the task it is supposed to perform as indicated by its name."*  Anyway, I feel the terminology needs to get sorted out here... because I had been doing a lot of `throw make error! "..."` because I thought that was what you were supposed to do, and took it upon myself to then parse out the error object to print and quit... not realizing I could DO the error and get the same behavior.  It is unlike other languages, and should be explained more clearly.